# Can I claim British citizenship?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

I intend to work and travel in/through the UK once I complete my degree, and I would like to know if I can apply for British citizenship.

I am an 18 year old (born 1997) South African, and I've lived in South Africa my entire life. My father is a UK citizen (born 1955), however he has lived in South Africa for 20+ years (after marrying my mother, a SA citizen).

My grandparents (on my fathers side) are both British, but served in the colonial service in Tanzania.

All my research thus far has yielded ambiguous forum answers, extortionate heritage tracing fees, and no clear answer. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Did you try the [official gov.uk checker](https://www.gov.uk/check-british-citizen)?

Comment: The question is whether your father was a citizen by descent or citizen otherwise by descent. The latter means that he was born in Britain. If yes, then you are most likely a british citizen (by descent).

Comment: (note, the duplicate's title says British mother, but for people born after 1997 it doesn't matter whether it's the mother or the father)

Comment: @SztupY: "The latter means that he was born in Britain." Not necessarily. For example, he could also have been born elsewhere and be a British citizen by naturalization, which is otherwise than by descent.

Comment: @user102008 yeah, you're right, I kept my comment somewhat too simple